# Mechanize and Nokogiri: trying to search items inside divs

Tags: ruby, regex, web-crawler

I'm setting up a crawler to get product information, for this I'm using mechanize and as a consequence nokogiri, I have a URL (http://www.megamamute.com.br/brother%205652) that returns only one product, but  I can't get the right regular expression to get the price of this item,what I want is inside the div called x-product:

HTML

```
<div class="pager top" id="PagerTop_66064345"></div><div id="ResultItems_66064345" class="prateleira vitrine"><div class="prateleira vitrine n1colunas"><ul><li layout="45e718bf-51b0-49c4-8882-725649af0594" class="informatica--teclado-notebook-tablet-pen-drive-|-megamamute last">

<input type="hidden" class="x-id" value="55492" />

<div class="x-product">

    <div class="x-selos">
        <p class="flag desconto-10--off-no-boleto">Desconto 10% off no boleto</p>

        <p class="flag Informática" style="display:none;">Informática</p>
    </div>

    <div class="x-get-skuId x-hide"><div class="buy-button-normal" id="55492" name="55492"><a class="buy-button-normal-a55492" href="https://www.megamamute.com.br/checkout/cart/add?sku=55492&qty=1&seller=1&sc=1&price=224900&cv=254ca7d1b9d7fb34e47ca55ceec1b2c0_geral:0F62E16B17B76A6FE17EC7C23A655D8B&sc=1" title="Comprar">Comprar</a><input type="hidden" value="cart" class="buy-button-normal-go-to-cart-55492" /></div></div>

    <div class="x-departamento">
        Multifuncional Laser Monocromática
    </div>

    <div class="x-image">
        <a class="x-productImage" title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p">
            <img src="http://megamamute.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/6658677-500-500/55492_original.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="55492_original" id="" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <h2 class="product-name">
        <a title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p">
            Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono
        </a>
    </h2>

    <div data-trustvox-product-code="55492"></div>

                <div class="x-price">
            <a title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p">

                                        <span class="oldPrice">
                         R$ 2.899,00
                    </span> 

                    <span class="x-bestPrice">
                        R$ 2.249,00 
                    </span>

                <span class="x-installment">
                                                 10X de <strong>R$ 224,90</strong> sem juros
                                        </em> 
            </a>

        </div>

        <!--<div class="x-opiniao">-->
        <!--    <span class="rating-produto avaliacao0">0</span> <span class="navaliacao">(0)</span>-->
        <!--</div>-->



        <div class="x-info-product">
            <ul>
                <li class="x-info"><a href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p"></a></li>
                <li class="x-favorite"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="x-move"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="x-add"><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="x-hover">
            <div class="x-buy"> <a class="x-productImage" title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p"> Comprar </a></div>
            <a class="x-hoverHref" title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p"></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="x-info"><a href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p"></a></li>
                <li class="x-favorite"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="x-move"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="x-add"><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>


    <div class="x-brand"><p class="texto brand brother">brother</p></div>
```

And I would like to go ahead and check how it would take to get several products, have several divs "x-product", I could not understand a way to assemble an array with all and get the information inside each one,

Below is my code snippet, is very simple,

Ruby snippet

```
require 'mechanize'
mechanize = Mechanize.new
agent= mechanize.get('http://www.megamamute.com.br/brother%205652
match = agent.search("/xproduct/")
puts match.html
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You can use CSS selectors and add the class of the price's container element:

```
require 'mechanize'
mechanize = Mechanize.new
agent= mechanize.get('http://www.megamamute.com.br/brother%205652')
match = agent.search(".x-product .x-bestPrice")
puts match.text.strip

#=> "R$ 2.249,00"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank You!